# Error: Permission Denied when changing preference Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Whenever I try to change the global setting (preferences) of Rstudio (for example unchecking the box that restores `.Rdata` into workspace upon startup as part of general options) and click 'apply' or  'ok', I receive

> "Error: Permission denied" and the changes were not made

(The error messages comes up regardless what change I make in the preferences). How, where and what kind of permission do I need to grant?

I have delete and re-installed R studio but the error messages keeps coming up. I am also running Rstudio as admin with read&write privileges.

I've seen the post on the Rstudio community (https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-permission-denied-when-settings-are-changed/88178) but I don't find the solution helpful.

> R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15) macOS Big Sur Version 11.5.2

Answer (score 3):

It's because Rstudio saves its preference in the `~\.config` folder which it do not have the permission to write.
You can change the permission of .config folder to solve.

```
sudo chown -R <username> .config
```

<username> should be replaced by your username. And you can run `whoami` command to check it out.